# Aspnetboilerplate application gives runtime error while applying sort on a query for ISoftDelete entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I want to write CRUD services for an entity named **Location** . Location has a composite primary key, so I couldn't use AsyncCrudAppService and copied the methods that I wanted from AsyncCrudAppService.

When I use GetAll Service without **ApplySorting** method, it works fine. But when I add sorting, I get this runtime error:

> [35] ERROR BookingSystem.middlewares.HttpGlobalExceptionFilter [(null)] - The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(l => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(((ISoftDelete)l).IsDeleted))
>       .OrderByDescending(l => l.Id)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). S
>   ee https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```
public class Location : IEntity<int>, IPassivable, IFullAudited<User> {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdLocation { get; set; }         //primary key 0
    public LocationType TypeId { get; set; }    //primary key 1
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ILocationService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<PagedResultDto<LocationDto>> GetAllAsync(PagedLocationResultRequestDto input);
}

public class LocationService : AbpServiceBase, ILocationService, IPerWebRequestDependency
{
    private readonly IRepository<Location, int> _repository;
    private IAsyncQueryableExecuter AsyncQueryableExecuter { get; set; }

    public LocationService(IRepository<Location> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        AsyncQueryableExecuter = NullAsyncQueryableExecuter.Instance;
    }


    public async Task<PagedResultDto<LocationDto>> GetAllAsync(PagedLocationResultRequestDto input)
    {
        if (input.MaxResultCount > _appSettings.Value.MaxResultCount)
        {
            throw new BookingSystemUserFriendlyException(BookingSystemExceptionCode.InputNotValid,
                nameof(input.MaxResultCount));
        }

        var query = CreateFilteredQuery(input);

        var totalCount = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.CountAsync(query);

        query = ApplySorting(query, input);
        query = ApplyPaging(query, input);

        var entities = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

        return new PagedResultDto<LocationDto>(
            totalCount,
            entities.Select(MapToEntityDto).ToList()
        );
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<Location> ApplySorting(
        IQueryable<Location> query, PagedLocationResultRequestDto input)
    {
        if (input is ISortedResultRequest sortInput &&
            !sortInput.Sorting.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            return query.OrderBy(sortInput.Sorting);
        }

        return query.OrderByDescending(e => e.Id);
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<Location> ApplyPaging(
        IQueryable<Location> query, PagedLocationResultRequestDto input)
    {
        if (input is IPagedResultRequest pagedInput)
        {
            return query.PageBy(pagedInput);
        }

        return query;
    }

    private IQueryable<Location> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedLocationResultRequestDto input)
    {
        return _repository.GetAll()
            .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Name),
                location => location.Name.ToLower().Contains(input.Name.Trim().ToLower()));
    }

    private LocationDto MapToEntityDto(Location entity)
    {
        return ObjectMapper.Map<LocationDto>(entity);
    }
}
```

Abp package version: 5.1.0

Base framework: .Net Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I asked the same question in the project's GitHub and got the answer.
In **ApplySorting**, the default sorting is based on **Id**, which doesn't exist in my database table.

> If you are using composite PK, then you probably don't have the Id field in the database, right? Then you should not sort by Id.

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5274#issuecomment-583946065